# How do i add a unique body class to the wordpress dashboard's home page?

Tags: dashboard, body-class

I installed a plugin that let me add my own css and html to the home page of the dashboard. This is great! However some of my styles are messing up other pages. I could solve this if the home page of the dashboard had a custom body class..

I looked at some example functions on stackoverflow but found nothing specifically targeting the dashboards home page.

Default page location: /wp-admin/index.php

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, you could just use `body.wp-admin.index-php` to target the dashboard.

If you want to add something else, you can use the [admin_body_class](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/admin_body_class/) filter to manipulate the classes added to the body and check what is displayed with [get_current_screen](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_current_screen):

```
add_filter("admin_body_class", function($classes) {
    $current_screen = get_current_screen();
    if($current_screen->base == "dashboard") {
        $classes .= " dashboard";
    }
    return $classes;
});
```